# Generic BiFunction that accepts generic wildcard

Tags: java, generics, java-8, enums, functional-programming

I have an enum and want to have a generic function that could accept any class that implements a maker interface.

```
public interface IComponentDataExporter { // Marker Interface }

public class ComponentsDataExporter implements IComponentDataExporter { 
  public ComponentTeaser populateFeatured(ComponentTeaserConfiguration componentConfig) { return null; } 
}
public class BusinessComponentsDataExporter implements IComponentDataExporter { // methods } 

public enum ComponentTypeEnum { 
  FEATURED(ComponentsDataExporter::populateFeatured); 
  
  public final BiFunction<? super IComponentDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfiguration, ComponentTeaser> exporter;

  private ComponentTypeEnum( BiFunction<? super IComponentDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfiguration, ComponentTeaser> exporter) {
  this.exporter = exporter;
  }
}
```

I am getting this compilation error `The type ComponentsDataExporter does not define populateFeatured(IComponentDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfiguration) that is applicable here`

My main issue is `BIFunction` I want it to accepts either `ComponentsDataExporter` or `BusinessComponentsDataExporter` that's why I tried to use a generic wildcard (? extends `IComponentDataExporter` and ? super `IComponentDataExporter`). It is working fine if I replace wildcard with a specific class.

---

### **Edit**

Sorry for not being clear in my questation so I will try to explain more and little of history.

I want to force whoever adding a new enum value to provide a method which is exporting data for that component. Logic of export method cannot be placed in Enum as it requires access to spring managed beans and may have a lot of business logic.

I already did that and it was working perefectly, you can have a look on this [demo](https://www.browxy.com/#USER_306739).

My problem started when I noticed that having all of export methods in one class will be too much so I decided to have different kind of implementation (`BusinessComponentsDataExporter` and `ComponentsDataExporter`) each one of them handles set of components.

To do that separation I have added a marker interface so I can mark any exporter class and updated BiFunction in Enum to have wildcard so it can accept any kind of object that implements my marker interface.

```
BiFunction<? super IComponentDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfiguration, ComponentTeaser> exporter
```

The solutions I am working on right now is reverting to my old version of BiFunction which was like the demo

```
BiFunction<ComponentsDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfiguration, ComponentTeaser>
```

Considering `ComponentsDataExporter` as facade which have instances of different kind of exporters where the whole exporting logic resides (`businessExporter`, `contentExporter` etc) so facade will have all high levels methods that can be called from Enum. Here's [example](https://www.browxy.com/#USER_306755) for the solution I am considering right now

Comment: what is FEATURED?

Comment: this is one of the enum values, this enum has different values (Featured and many other). I want to have exporter BIFunction for each item in enum.

Comment: oh I see, thats fancy. Maybe trying fixing you typos and see if it helps with compilation errors? `this.compoenentDataExporter=componentDataExporter` - you keep calling component sometimes correctly and sometimes with typos

Comment: thank you for telling this, may be I runied my snippet  while make it simpler so I had some typos but this is not my issue. I will fix the snippet.

Comment: actually now that i see it it is very simple - you are implementing an interface but don't define/implement the methods of the interface in ComponentsDataExporter

Comment: Actually my interface is empty. I do not have any methods in interface to implment. it is just a marker interface.

Comment: My issue is mainly in BIFunction, I want my BIFunction to accpet either ComponentsDataExporter or BusinessComponentsDataExporter as those two classes will have different methods for different component types. It is mainly for modularizing and separate methods into diffferent classes.

Comment: I get it but that is not what the compilation error says? did you copy the error message correctly?

Comment: Yes I have copied correctly. It is working fine if I change my BIFunction to point to specific class without wildcard in the first argument. BIFunction<ComponentsDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfig, ComponentTeaser> or BIFunction<BusinessComponentsDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfig, ComponentTeaser> both are working fine.

Comment: regarding that point you should anyways be using `? extends` as you are looking for things that extend/implement and not super to `IComponentDataExporter`

Comment: I tried both ? extends and ? super and faced the same issue.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with your assignment of exporter. It is clearly to do with `populateFeatured`. The way extential type parameter is fine and I cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/JX9uzw (but you should use `extends` instead of `super` as the other mentioned.

Comment: There is no sense in using wildcards here, they do not improve anything. You have to fix the fundamental flaw of your intention: you have a *marker* interface that does not declare any methods, but want to use a method reference that assumes that a particular method is *always* there, in all implementations. But the marker interface does not guaranty that the method is there. There are simple solutions, e.g. declare the method in the interface if all implementations are assumed to have it.

Comment: „*...I want to have exporter BIFunction for each item in enum...*“ — By „*each item*“ do you mean „*each* [*enum constant*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1)“? You're initializing the 1 _`BiFunction`_ in the 1 constructor. Wouldn't initializing a different _`BiFunction`_ for each different enum constant need a different constructor for each enum constant? *Each one a subsignature of the other*? Good luck with that! I'd love to learn why a design based on enums is better than simpler, more orthodox approaches. Please help me learn something new today? TIA.

Comment: „*e.g. declare the method in the interface if all implementations are assumed to have it*“  – @Holger My understanding of what OP means by: „*ComponentsDataExporter or BusinessComponentsDataExporter as those two classes **will have different methods for different component types***“, is that the different methods of each individual concrete _`IComponentDataExporter`_ will each have different method signatures. I gather the rationale for the „*Marker*“ interface is that there isn't supposed to be any common method(*s*) that all implementations would override from _`IComponentDataExporter`_.

Comment: @deduper this might be the intention, but then, it’s impossible to do that way. You can’t use a method reference only working for a particular implementation type to initialize a function that promises to handle all implementations of the marker interface.

Comment: „*...it’s impossible to do that way...*“ — Yup @Holger. There's a good chance OP has realized that by now. Probably why I'm not getting anymore replies from him to my follow-up questions.

Comment: @Holger, I agree with you regarding no point of having wildcards here and the only solution is to have all methods in one place either interface or one class but it won't fit for me on level of exporter class as each one of them will have differnet methods. I decided to move to Facade that will hide different exporter implementations. Facade will list all methods so it can be used in Enum.

Comment: @deduper the main idea of doing that inside Enum is to force everyone adding new constant to that enum. in my case a new component type he has to provide a method which will export data for that component. Also by doing this I am getting rid of switch statement.

Comment: I think you both were right, it will be impossible to do it that way as no gurantee that methods will be there in passed instance by just having markere interface. Compiler needs to be sure that your method are there if you want to get the benefit of using first biFunction argument as target object. I think using facade will achieve that for me as it will be the place listing all functions that can be called from Enum. Behind that facade I can manage different implements for each set of components.

Comment: Thank you, Ahmed. — „*...it will be impossible to do it that way...*“ — Even if you somehow managed a way around your marker interface problem, you would still have this other impossibility: „*...I want to have exporter BIFunction for each item in enum...*“ — I demonstrate the problem you would face [*in this experiment*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306748).

Comment: No I would not face that problem as all of the components are accepting the same config object and returning the same type. The difference only in the data each component expose. you can have a look on that [demo](https://www.browxy.com/#USER_306755) to get the idea.

Comment: Clever! I love learning something new everyday :) Thanks! —  „*ComponentsDataExporter or BusinessComponentsDataExporter as those two classes **will have different methods for different component types***“ — So by „*different methods*“ you mean the name   _`populateCreatured(ComponentTeaserConfiguration)::ComponentTeaser`_ is different from  _`populateFeatured(ComponentTeaserConfiguration)::ComponentTeaser`_. I misinterpreted „different component types“ to mean „*the different methods will take different component types as arguments and return different component types*“. It's clearer now. Thx.

Comment: Hey Ahmed? I've always known that [_`Enums` can have methods, fields, constructors_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3), etc. like a *normal* class. I'd even coded *toy* implementations of _`Enums`_ with all those members in the past. But I never could envisage a real-world use case for such an _`Enum`_.  I'm intrigued to learn from your use case. When you have ***a spare 10 minutes*** please teach me your ways :) No rush. [*Can we chat*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219606/til-something-new-from-ahmed-yousef) whenever it's convenient for you? TIA.

Comment: sure we can arrange a quick chat together

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully what your error message says…

> „...*`ComponentsDataExporter does not define populateFeatured(IComponentDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfiguration)`*...“

[*`BiFunction<T,U,R>` is defined to take **two** input arguments*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html). But you define *`populateFeatured(ComponentTeaserConfiguration)`* with only ***one*** parameter…

```
...
public ComponentTeaser populateFeatured(ComponentTeaserConfiguration componentConfig)...
...
```

So you <strike>*need to*</strike> *could* rewrite it [*like I do here*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306422)…

```
...
public static ComponentTeaser populateFeatured( IComponentDataExporter self, ComponentTeaserConfiguration componentConfig )... 
...
```

Notice it's *`static`* [*in my demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306422). If you want to use a method reference (*`FEATURED(ComponentsDataExporter::populateFeatured)`*) then the method either has to be *`static`* or you need an object instance to call it if it's not *`static`* (`new ComponentsDataExporter()::populateFeatured`).

And then the *`BiFunction`* changes to…

```
...
BiFunction< IComponentDataExporter, ComponentTeaserConfiguration, ComponentTeaser >...
...
```

An upper bound wildcard (*`? extends IComponentDataExporter`*) as the first type argument to your *`BiFunction`* wouldn't compile. A lower bound wildcard (*`? super IComponentDataExporter`*) would actually work there. But it would be confusing. It's better off being specified as simply a normal interface type argument (`IComponentDataExporter`).

That would then be used like…

```
ComponentTeaserConfiguration conf = null;
    
BusinessComponentsDataExporter exp = null;
    
ComponentTypeEnum featured = ComponentTypeEnum.FEATURED;
    
ComponentTeaser teaser = featured.export( exp, conf );
    
teaser.tease( );
```

Click the green *Start* button at the top of the demo to see it run.

---

***EDIT***: If I understand your follow-up comments correctly, I don't think you want a [*`BiFunction`*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) at all.

From what I gather from your comments — *and your original implementation of `populateFeatured(...)`* — if seems like what you *actually* want is a [*`Function`*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html)…

```
...
Function< ComponentTeaserConfiguration, ComponentTeaser >...
...
```

Because your questions and comments are not crystal clear, these suggestions are based on what I *assume* your intention is.

> „*…the call will be something like this `ComponentTypeEnum.Featured.exporter.apply(exporterInstance, configObj)`…*“

One of the things that you have not made crystal clear is the reason why you need to pass a *`IComponentDataExporter`* into *`populateFeatured(...)`*, given that *`ComponentsDataExporter`* is ***itself*** a concrete implementation of *`IComponentDataExporter`*. Please update your question with *something* that clarifies that?

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I use populateFeatured with one argument as the first one will be used as instance so the call will be something like this `ComponentTypeEnum.Featured.exporter.apply(exporterInstance, configObj);`. This is actually working if I use specific class (ComponentDataExporter or BusinessExporter) in my BIFunction. Fo me it would be useless to keep passing the self reference in all populate methods, I think it should be enough to pass only while calling apply.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by: „*I use populateFeatured with one argument as the first one will be used as instance*“. [*The rules say*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) that any method used as a _`BiFunction`_ ***MUST*** take ***two*** arguments. The prefix ***Bi*** in _`BiFunction`_ means ***Two***. — „*This is actually working if I use specific class*“ — Please post a simple example of such „*actually working*“ code? Try [*Ideone*](http://ideone.com). You would be teaching me something I never knew was even possible. So TIA.

Comment: See for example `BiFunction<String,Charset,byte[]> f = String::getBytes;`. The method `getBytes(Charset)` has only one parameter, but the `String` object on which you will invoke it makes the first parameter for the `BiFunction`.

Comment: Ahh! OK. Thank you @Holger. Learn something new every day :) I was in the process of editing my answer before I read your comment. I went back and edited my edit accordingly, knowing what you've just explained. Thanks again.

Comment: @AhmedYousef I've [*changed my demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306422) to reflect the edits I made in my answer. And again, ***please*** update your question with ***something*** that clarifies why you need to pass an instance of _`IComponentDataExporter`_ into a method call of the same _`IComponentDataExporter`_??? Or have I misunderstood your explanation of that too? With a design that is as unclear and as *unorthodox* as yours is, the more information you can share, the better the answers you're offered will be.

Comment: @deduper sorry for not being clear. I have edited my question. As Holger said the first argument of Bifunction can be used as target object to invoke your function. He already shared a good example of getBytes in String. I cannot use function instead of Bifunction because I will have to make all export methods static which won't be feasible in my case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Although your enum approach isn't one I'd opt for, I persisted because the best way for me to learn new stuff is to keep an open mind. For example your use case reminds me of the [*Sealed Classes*](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/datum.html#sealed-types) feature introduced [*in JDK 15*](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/15/). Your _`exporters`_ fit the description of the „*sum types*“ Goetz talks about in that link. I'll port my demo solution to sealed types as a learning exercise. Is [*using JDK 15*](https://jdk.java.net/15/) an option for your project?

Comment: Unfortunately JDK 15 won't be an option in that project. It is quite old code base using java 8. I will have a look on sealed classes to know more about it. If you have more suggestions or ideas I  am all ears even if I cannot use in that project, it will good to learn new stuff.

Comment: „*suggestions or ideas*“ — Goetz's *Datum* page I shared above. [*Valhalla is also good to know about*](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/valhalla/sov/01-background.html) if you don't already. Educate your managers: [*8 is no safer than 14*](https://old.reddit.com/r/java/comments/i5zyyk/wtf_does_lts_even_mean_ffs/g0tx2kd/) and [*JDK 8 is an antiquated, bloated and slow runtime*](https://old.reddit.com/r/java/comments/i5c8wl/how_much_of_new_java_software_is_written_using/g0s399d/). [*Download JDK 15*](https://jdk.java.net/15/) or [*16*](https://jdk.java.net/16/) and play around with it.

Comment: @AhmedYousef? To understand the pros of an _`Enum`_-based design, I refactored [*my demo*](https://www.browxy.com/#USER_306780) to not use _`Enums`_. I refactored [_your `Enum`-based demo_](https://www.browxy.com/#USER_306760) to make both demos function identically. _`Enums`_ share some of the pros of Sealed Classes and Records. I used your _`Enums`_ as _`switch`_ labels to do the same job I could only do with _`if/else`_  in mine. Overall, _`Enums`_ with behavior are an intriguing design choice. Thanks for sharing the idea. I hope one day I'll have an appropriate use case to apply it to