# Type inference with method reference and primitive types

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Is there a way to tell Java to NOT try to infer a type from a method reference that uses primitive types?

Here is a method that I wrote, the reason for this is irrelevant right now:

```
    public static <F, T> Predicate<F> isEquals(
            Function<F, T> aInMapFunction, T aInExpectedValue)
    {
        return aInActual -> Objects.equals(
                aInMapFunction.apply(aInActual), aInExpectedValue);
    }
```

Now, what if you pass a method reference to "isEquals" that returns a primitive type?

```
Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = isEquals(String::length, 20);
```

This is all fine and dandy, except that Java will also accept this strange usage:

```
Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = isEquals(String::length, "what the heck?!?!?");
```

This is because the compiler will infer type parameter T as "`Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>`", which will accept both Integer and String types.

This is undesirable, in my case, as I would like a compilation error rather than Java figuring out some crazy type argument. For my thing, I can also explicitly override method "isEquals" to take specific primitive types. For example:

```
    public static <F> Predicate<F> isEquals(
            ToIntFunction<F> aInMapFunction, int aInExpectedValue)
    {
        return aInActual ->
                aInMapFunction.applyAsInt(aInActual) == aInExpectedValue;
    }
```

This works fine, this method is invoked rather than the Object one when I pass in a method that returns a primitive int. The problem is that I still need the Object method, I cannot remove it, which will still cause the compiler to accept the weird invocation I listed above.

So the question is: is there a way for me to tell Java to not use the Object version of isEquals when the method reference returns a primitive type? I couldn't find anything, I'm feeling I'm out of luck in this one.

(NOTE: the actual implementation of the object version of isEquals works fine and should be safe. This is because Object.equals and Object**s**.equals accept Object parameters and a String object will never be equals to an Integer object. Semantically, however, this looks weird)

EDIT: after the comment from "paranoidAndroid", one idea that I just had is to wrap the method reference the following way:

```
    public static <T> Function<T, Integer> wrap(ToIntFunction<T> aInFunction)
    {
        return aInFunction::applyAsInt;
    }
```

And now,

```
Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = isEquals(wrap(String::length), "what the heck?!?!?");
```

... generates a compilation error. Still not great though, maybe there is a better way. At least this is better than passing the type in explicitly, which kind of beats the purpose.

EDIT 2: I'm in Java 8 right now. Java 11 might behave differently here, I didn't test.

EDIT 3: I'm thinking there is nothing we can do here, this is just an implication of how type inference works in Java. Here is another example:

```
    public static <T> boolean isEquals(T t1, T t2) {
        return Objects.equals(t1, t2);
    }
```

with this method, the following expression is perfectly valid:

```
System.out.println(isEquals(10, "20"));
```

This works because Java will try to resolve the type for T based on a common upper bound. It just happens that both Integer and String share the same upper bound `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>`

Comment: I do not see why `Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = isEquals(String::length, "what the heck?!?!?")` is strange behaviour. It's just the consequence of type inference.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to agree with you, this is just how type inference works. After reading a bit the spec (not much though, the spec is crazy), you can see that inference tries to create bounds for different "inference variables" and then it proceeds to find the most common "proper types" that satisfy the given constraints, which results in this behaviour. Semantically I still find this a bit weird, but I can live with it.

Comment: Referring to your edit 3: but i don't see how it's related to Comparable. Even this compiles: isEquals(new Object(), "abc");

Comment: Your last example doesn't make any sense lol. (I mean, this is really, really strange)

Comment: „*...this is really, really **strange**...*“ — @paranoidAndroid — Yeah, that's one way to put it. I call it: „*Not obvious*“ or „*subtle*“; maybe even „*nuanced*“ or „*It's complicated*“. That's my characterization of Java's type inference rules. And that's after having read and reread [*the JLS chapter on it*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-18.html) 3 or 4 times at this point. To reduce the complexity of ch18 to be easily digestible/easily remembered, I abstract it in my mind to a simplified term: „[*Specifying a bound*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386541/4465539)“.

Comment: „*...I still find this a bit **weird**...*“ — MarcioLucca? — I would call it „*mathematically rigorous*“, myself, before I would call it „*weird*“. Now, what I would call „*weird*“ is the naming convention for variables used in your question: „*`lLengthIs20`...`aInMapFunction`...`aInExpectedValue`*“. HehHeh ;) No offense. But I had to change them when [*I tried to reproduce*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63386541/4465539) your „*weird*“ behavior because they were making me feel _`aNxious`_ :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is not a bug, but a consequence of type inference. OP already mentioned it. The compiler will not try to match an exact type, but *the most specific one*.

Let us analyse how type inference works with the example provided by OP.

```
public static <F, T> Predicate<F> isEquals(Function<F, T> func, T expValue) {
    return actual -> Objects.equals(func.apply(actual), expValue);
}
```

```
Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = isEquals(String::length, "Whud?");
```

Here the target type is `Predicate<String>`, and according to the return type of the method, which is `Predicate<F>` (where `F` is a generic type), `F` is bound to a `String`. Then the method reference `String::length` is checked whether it fits into the method parameter `Function<F, T>`, where `F` is `String` and `T` some unbounded type. And this is important: while the method reference `String::length` looks like its target type is `Integer`, it is also compatible to `Object`. Similarly, `Object obj = "Hello".length()` is valid. It is not *required* to be an `Integer`. Likewise, both `Function<String, Object> func = String::length` and `Function<String, Object> func = str -> str.length()` are valid and do not emit a compiler warning.

### What exactly is inference?

Inference is to defer the job of selecting the appropriate type to the compiler. You ask the compiler: "Please, could you fill in appropriate types, so that it'll work?" And then the compiler answers: "Okay, but I follow certain rules when selecting the type."

The compiler selects the most specific type. In the case of `isEquals(String::length, 20)`, both the target type of `String::length` and `20` is `Integer`, so the compiler infers it as such.

However, in the case of `isEquals(String::length, "Whud?")` the compiler first tries to infer `T` to an `Integer` because of the type of `String::length`, but it fails to do so because of the type of the second argument. The compiler then tries to find the closest intersection of `Integer` and `String`.

### Can I aid or bypass the compiler?

Bypass? No, not really. Well, sometimes typecasting is a way of bypassing, like in the following example:

```
Object o = 23; // Runtime type is integer
String str = (String) o; // Will throw a ClassCastException
```

The typecast here is a potentially unsafe operation, because `o` may or may not be a `String`. With this typecast, you say to the compiler: "In this specific case, I know better than you" – with the risk of getting an exception during runtime.

Still, not all typecast operations are permitted:

```
Integer o = 23;
String str = (String) o;
// Results in a compiler error: "incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to String"
```

But you can certainly aid the compiler.

#### Type witness

One option may be to **use a *type witness***:

```
Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = YourClass.<String, Integer>isEquals(String::length, "what?");
```

This code will emit a compiler error:

> incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer

#### Add a `Class<T>` parameter to `isEquals`

Another option would be to **add a parameter** to `isEquals`:

```
public static <F, T> Predicate<F> isEquals(Class<T> type, Function<F, T> func, T expValue) {
    return actual -> Objects.equals(func.apply(actual), expValue);
}
```

```
// This will succeed:
Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = isEquals(Integer.class, String::length, 20);
// This will fail:
Predicate<String> lLengthIs20 = isEquals(Integer.class, String::length, "Whud?");
```

#### Typecasting

A third option may be ***typecasting***. Here you cast `String::length` to a `Function<String, Integer>`, and now the compiler is restricted to `F = String, T = Integer`. Now the usage of `"Whud?"` causes trouble.

```
Predicate<String> predicate = isEquals((Function<String, Integer>) String::length, "Whud?");
```

Comment: I still don't get it. If I pass a Function<String, Integer> (which is String::length) T is Integer, not some supertype of integer. T must conform to Integer. So the method parameter 'aInExpectedValue', declared T, must be Integer. What am I missing?

Comment: Furthermore, if we were to pass a Class<T> reference into the isEquals() method - everything works as expected. What is the difference between Class<T> and Function<F,T> ?

Comment: „*...What is the difference between Class<T> and Function<F,T> ? ...*“ — 1 ***major*** difference, is that *in  `Function<F,T>`'s case* the „*method*“ that 's created under the hood gets a [*receiver parameter*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4-300) that will be of type _`F`_. I learned about that just the other day from @Holger in a question about [_`BiFunction`_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63333826/4465539)s. Thanks again, Holger :) Not saying OP's thing can be attributed to that difference. But repeating new things I learned helps me remember them :)

Comment: Thanks MC Emperor. In the example you gave above you are bypassing type inference, which works, of course. I'm thinking this may be the only solution. Maybe in future versions of the language they may give programmers tools to help the compiler figure out the right types, but for now this doesn't seem to be the case. Type inference is a very complicated topic, the spec does talk about using simplifications at times to try and avoid making a complex problem even more difficult.

Comment: „*...In the example you gave above you are bypassing type inference...*“ — @MarcioLucca? His answer hinges on the „*type witness*“ he refers to and shows in his example. My understanding is that a „*type witness*“ does the opposite of „*bypassing type inference*“. I always thought using a type witness ***aids** type inference*. Is that not the case?

Comment: "type witness" is a new concept for me. What I thought that syntax allows you is it allows you to explicitly specify the type argument to use. The language of course will make sure the type arguments satisfy the type parameter bounds, etc, but ultimately you are explicitly telling the compiler what type (arguments) to use.

Comment: @MarcioLucca. This: „*...the **inference engine** just doesn't have enough to go on...we can give it **a hint** if we specify the types we **know** to be true..just like **a type witness** in Java...*“ — ([*Scala for Java Developers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=dQlDDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=%22type+witness%22+generics+%22hint%22&source=bl&ots=iy-klu0KW2&sig=ACfU3U1JWuzI8I2x15hucal0UOtX-LgXbA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD2baE6pjrAhXSh1wKHTrqAz8Q6AEwEnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22type%20witness%22%20generics%20%22hint%22&f=false)) is the gist of how I think of „*type witness*“ in my own mind.

Comment: Yes, a *type witness* is an explicit note to the compiler from the developer, saying "I, as a developer, *intend* that these are the data types I want them to be". The compiler then performs the appropriate type checks based on the explicit types. This is not bypassing, this is aiding the compiler.

Comment: Still I don't understand why the compiler doesn't infer T as Integer from String::length. I know what a type witness is, it is usually used when the compiler cannot infer the type parameters. For example,: List<String[]> l = Arrays.<String[]>asList(new String[] { "a", "b"});. Type witness is normally useful only in a very small number of cases. But still I would expect T to be inferred as Integer - the fact that it works if I assign it to a variable first. But still the compiler has all the needed information to do it without the type witness, in the call itself...

Comment: @deduper  you are referring to F, what about T? is T totally ignored in this case? The problem here is with T, not F

Comment: Yes. I was referring to _`F`_, @paranoidAndroid. — „*...what about T?...*“ — Honest answer: I don't know. Not 100% of the details anyway. But my *general*  understanding of what's happening with _`T`_  is: *It's almost certainly a function of  „generic method applicability testing“ done by the inference engine* (*see ch18 of the JLS*). — „*is T totally ignored in this case?*“ — I ***am*** 100% sure _`T`_ is not ignored. In every error I saw when demoing, _`T`_ is always mentioned.The err msgs describe its bounds, the method it's declared in, the fact that it's an *inference variable*, etc.

Comment: I edited the question with another funny (?) example. It seems this is simply how type inference works, what are you gonna do... :-/

Comment: @MCEmperor I'm now referring to your last edit. I would still expect that T should be the same class - or subclass... Because String::length, of course Integer is assignable to an Object. But the concrete return type is Integer. So, logically, as a user, I would expect to enforce T as Integer. All the required information is available to the compiler at compile time.. This behavior is really strange to me.. If I write for example: someMethod(T object, Class<T> objClass) you can also say that any class of T is assignable to an object. but someMethod(T obj1, T obj2) behaves differently..

Comment: I think I see your point now. the compiler tries its best to match the arguments, so it upcasts from Integer to Object and from whatever other argument there is, to Object. Otherwise if we had two different objects with common superclass, it wouldn't work. Still odd-looking to me, but I learned something :)

Comment: @paranoidAndroid *"T must conform to Integer"* — No, it must not. The type of the second parameter of `isEquals` is also `T`, so both `Integer` and `String` are equally (in)appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> „*…is there a way for me to tell Java to not use the Object version…*“

Yes. And the term — *in the context of Generics* — for telling Java to not use `Object` is called: „*Specifying a bound*“.

[My experiment confirmed](https://jdoodle.com/ia/fw) that calling the following method as `isEquals(String::hashCode, "What the theoretical fuck!&?*!?@!")` will produce `error: no suitable method found for isEquals(String::hashCode,String)`...

```
public static <F extends String, T extends Number> Predicate<F> isEquals(Function<F, T> aFunction, T aValue)
{
    return input -> Objects.equals(aFunction.apply(input), aValue);
}
```

If you have both, the above method, and the following one in the same class, then this version is called for `isEquals(String::length, 20)`...

```
public static <F> Predicate<F> isEquals(ToIntFunction<F> aFunction, int aValue)
{
    return input -> aFunction.applyAsInt(input) == aValue;
}
```

...But the first one is called for `isEquals(String::length, Integer.valueOf(42))`.

Click the blue *Execute* button [*in this demo*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/fw) to see it working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer deduper. The problem is that I don't want to specify a bound to T, as T is supposed to be generic, that is, it may or may not be a Number. If I want to use for example `Predicate<String> p = isEquals(Boolean::parseBoolean, true)`, then it wouldn't compile either, which is no good. Finally, I don't want to have to specify a new method every time I need to use a new type, as that would not be super generic.

Comment: BTW, I think that online IDE I pointed you at, has a bug. Does the _`MyClass.java`_  editor window show up empty when you click on [*the link I shared*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/fw)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, this smells like a real java compiler bug to me..Compiler should be able to infer arguments without assignment to a variable, since we have `Function<F, T> aInMapFunction` which should enforce T, as the compiler "knows" that `String::length` returns an Integer.
However I came up with a sort of solution for you:

```
public class PredicateBuilder<F,T>
{
    public Predicate<F> isEquals(
            Function<F, T> aInMapFunction, T aInExpectedValue)
    {
        return aInActual -> Objects.equals(
                aInMapFunction.apply(aInActual), aInExpectedValue);
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
new PredicateBuilder<String, Integer>().isEquals(String::length, 5);
```

Won't compile with other argument types, won't compile either if you try this:

```
new PredicateBuilder<>().isEquals(String::length, 5);
```

Comment: Yes, this is one idea. Basically this is bypassing type inference, as you are providing the types in the function call, or in your case, when you create the PredicateBuilder.

Comment: This is **not** a compiler bug, but rather simply how inference works. The rules are slightly complicated, but they are defined very well. See [Java Language Specification, chapter 18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-18.html).

Comment: @MarcioLucca Yes, I think, after the long discussion, that this is the only way to enforce type correctness in your use case.